# How to implement Soundex in Dotnet Lucene?

Tags: lucene.net

I need to implement Soundex in my lucene project .In Lucene dotnet documentation there is no clear explanation regarding it nor i can find it anywhere in the internet.It would be very much helpful if someone has came across this situation?

https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00009/api/analysis-phonetic/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Phonetic.Language.Soundex.html